# What are the minimum/maximum integers in gprolog?

Tags: integer, prolog, iso-prolog

What are the minimum/maximum integers in gprolog? Is there a way to reference these numbers without using a "magic number"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think these should work:

```
current_prolog_flag(bounded, X).
current_prolog_flag(min_integer, Y).
current_prolog_flag(max_integer, Z).
```

`bounded` tells you whether your implementation supports arbitrary large integers; if it's false, the `min_integer` / `max_integer` calls will fail.

Comment: Also note that, as the question tags hint, `bounded`, `min_integer`, and `max_integer` are ISO Prolog Core standard specified flags and you can use them with most Prolog systems.